# How to grab minimum date for count of while doing group by date?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, postgresql-9.3

(this builds on a previous question I asked) I have a table called users that holds users ids, as well as a few tables like `cloud_storage_a`, `cloud_storage_b` and `cloud_storage_c`. If a user exists in cloud_storage_a, that means they are a connected to cloud storage a. A user can exist in many cloud storages too. Here's an example:

```
id      | address      | name      | created_at
--------------------------------------------------
123     | 23 Oak Ave   | Melissa   | 2014-05-12
333     | 18 Robson Rd | Steve     | 2015-01-20
421     | 95 Ottawa St | Helen     | 2015-02-10
555     | 12 Highland  | Amit      | 2015-05-17
192     | 39 Anchor Rd | Oliver    | 2015-08-25
```

`cloud_storage_a`

```
user_id | created_at
---------------------
 421    | 2015-03-05
 333    | 2015-02-01
```

`cloud_storage_b`

```
user_id | created_at
----------------------
 555    | 2015-07-20
```

`cloud_storage_c`

```
user_id | created_at
---------------------
 192    | 2015-08-26
 555    | 2015-08-01
```

I have a query to determine the number of users that joined any account from the time they signed up:

```
SELECT
    concat(extract(MONTH FROM u.created_at),
            '-',extract(YEAR FROM u.created_at)) AS "Month-Year",
    count(s1.user_id) AS "# of Users that Signed up on Any Cloud"
FROM (
        SELECT user_id, created_at FROM cloud_storage_a
        UNION
        SELECT user_id, created_at FROM cloud_storage_b
        UNION 
        SELECT user_id, created_at FROM cloud_storage_c
    ) AS s1
    INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = s1.user_id
GROUP BY
    1,
    EXTRACT(MONTH from u.created_at),
    EXTRACT(YEAR from u.created_at)
ORDER BY
    EXTRACT(YEAR from u.created_at),
    EXTRACT(MONTH from u.created_at);
```

But from my understanding - this does not grab the minimum. (Ie for user 555, they joined cloud b 07-2015 and cloud c 08-2015. I don't think my query now counts for that minimum date - how would i accomplish this?

Comment: Do you want month-year and count of users created on that month, which are joined any storage account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,  as far as I understand your desired output you only need to add `DISTINCT` to your `COUNT()` function, Moreover I think it's more readable if do the logic (grupping by two columns, ordered the output) in a subquery and the format output in higher level query. So in the end:

```
SELECT "Month" || '-' || "Year", "Count"
FROM (
    SELECT
        extract(MONTH from u.created_at) as "Month", extract(YEAR from u.created_at)) as "Year",
        count(DISTINCT u.id) as "Count"
    FROM users u
        JOIN (  SELECT user_id, created_at FROM cloud_storage_a
                UNION
                SELECT user_id, created_at FROM cloud_storage_b
                UNION
                SELECT user_id, created_at FROM cloud_storage_c
        ) AS s1 ON  s1.user_id = u.id
                    AND u.created_at <= s1.created_at
    GROUP BY
        EXTRACT(MONTH from u.created_at),
        EXTRACT(YEAR from u.created_at)
    ORDER BY
        EXTRACT(YEAR from u.created_at),
        EXTRACT(MONTH from u.created_at)
) sub
```

I also added date checking to fulfill your requirement of

> ...joined any account from the time they signed up...

Answer (score 0):

After your table definition `cloud_storage_a` I stopped reading.

Bad table design. What you define as a table should be a row in a table. You should not continue work on this data model.

Consider something like this:

```
create table cloudstorages (
  id serial not null primary key, 
     -- more attributes...
  info text);

create table user_storage (
  id      serial not null primary key,
  uid     integer references users(id),
  storage integer references cloudstorages(id)
  );
```

Then come back here with the new design if it still does not work out.

Edit: just saw your date formatting. Have a look at [data type formatting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-formatting.html) with to_char().

Edit: you must use these tables, well... I would make year and month 2 columns in the result set, this should help grouping.

Comment: Yes this has been noted (I did not create these structures and unfortunately can't change them)